# Any idea how to add manifest.json to html head dynamiclly

Tags: reactjs, umijs

I realized that, by default, the umi project does not have `manifest.json`. I added the file to the `public` folder manually. Then, after compiling the application through the `umi build` command, my custom file is merged with the`dist` folder.

But is there any way to add the meta header to the self-generated `index.html` file?

I have not been able to find anything in the UMI docs. My guess, I need to build a script to insert it into the file after it is fully compiled.

Anything would be helpfull.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the pro.ant.design, you can find the index.html in `/src/pages/document.ejs`. It is a templated version of the index page.